# Send NSString as body of post method using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsurlsession

I am trying to post a string to a server using the next example:

```
// 1
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_WEBSERVICE_URL"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

// 2
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// 3
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"key1": @"value1"};
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary 
  options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (!error) {
 // 4
 NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
   fromData:data completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
   // Handle response here
   }];

   // 5
   [uploadTask resume];
}
```

The difference is that I don't have a NSDictionary But an NSString object that stores an array of dictionaries, and also the string that I post must not be encoded it must be a simple string, so it is visible in the search field if I manually enter it.

My NSString example:

```
[{
    "api_id" = debugger;
    at = "2015-02-05T01:41:13Z";
    oS = IOS;
    ver = "8.10";
    what = "showAdAt: forViewController:";
},
{
    "api_id" = debugger;
    at = "2015-02-05T01:41:13Z";
    oS = IOS;
    ver = "8.10";
    what = "showAdAt: forViewController:";
}
]
```

Thank you in advance and be patient with me as this is my first post attempt.
I was thinking that the above example should work for me if I first convert the NSString to NSArray with dictionaries as objects.

UPDATE:

Currently I am trying to post the string as:

```
            NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                                           @"Authorization"       : @"CUSTOM AUTHORIZATION THAT I AM USING",
                                                           @"Content-Type"        : @"application/json"
                                                           };

            // Create the session
            // We can use the delegate to track upload progress
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

            // Data uploading task. We could use NSURLSessionUploadTask instead of NSURLSessionDataTask if we needed to support uploads in the background
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MY WEBSITE LINK"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";            
            //Convert the string to NSData 
   bodyContainerString = @"[{\"api_id\":\"A124\",\"at\":\"2011-04-10T20:09:31Z\",\"os\":\"ANDROID\",\"ver\":\"2.1\",\"what\":\"TEST\",\"value\":\"\"},{\"api_id\":\"A124\",\"at\":\"2011-04-10T20:10:31Z\",\"os\":\"ANDROID\",\"ver\":\"2.1\",\"what\":\"TEST\",\"value\":\"\"}]";
            NSData* jsonData = [bodyContainerString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            jsonData = [jsonData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [jsonData length] - 1)];

            NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSLog(newStr);

            request.HTTPBody = jsonData;
            NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                // Process the response
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
                if (!error && httpResp.statusCode == 201) {
                    //if no error on upload then delete content of plist
                    NSLog(@"Success  on post1");
                }
                 NSLog(@"Success  on post2");
            }];
            [uploadTask resume];
```

Update 2, the resulting link should look like:

```
curl -X POST  http://MY_LINK/smtg -H 'Authorization: CUSTOM_FIRST_HEADER' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"api_id":"A124","at":"2011-04-10T20:09:31Z","os":"ANDROID","ver":"2.1","what":"TEST","value":""},{"api_id":"A124","at":"2011-04-10T20:10:31Z","os":"ANDROID","ver":"2.1","what":"TEST","value":""}]'
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking here. Are you saying that the top code block is some example code that you found and the bottom block is the contents of an `NSString` that you would like to post instead of the `NSDictionary` in the example?

Comment: What about `request.HTTPBody = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: @midhun-mp I have just uploaded the code that I am using

Comment: So you want to make a HTTP POST request, and the POST is like myKey=aJSONString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the first example that I found here is my implementation:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_LINK/smtg"];


//Create thhe session with custom configuration
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                               @"Authorization"       : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BEARER %@",finalToken],
                                               @"Content-Type"        : @"application/json"
                                               };

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

// 2
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

// 3

NSError *error = nil;

NSData* jsonData = [bodyContainerString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


if (!error) {
    // 4
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                                               fromData:jsonData completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error) {
                                                                   // Handle response here
                                                               }];

    // 5
    [uploadTask resume];
}}
```